# Set JQuery DataTable Columns Width manually

Tags: jquery, datatable, width, manual, dynamic-columns

I am using JQuery datatable latest plugin. I have issue with header and body columns are not aligned. What I am trying to do is I want to read each header column's width and corresponding body column's width and set the maximum of two to both th and td. But I am not able to read the width property of th or td. How can I do this?

I tried the following which returns blank

```
$("myTable thead tr th).each(function(){ var width = $(this).width});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use below, replace `width` with `width()`. `$(this)` should call function and not property.

**NOTE** - you have missed clossing quotes for `$("myTable thead tr th)`, correct it.

```
$("myTable thead tr th").each(function(){ var width = $(this).width()});
```

If you want to use property then use `this` instead of `$(this)`

```
$("myTable thead tr th").each(function(){ var width = this.width});
```